# What is my BaseDN supposed to be with the following configuration of OpenLDAP?

Tags: authentication, ldap, remote-access, openldap

I have the following in my OpenLDAP configuration. Using the latest version OpenLDAP on Centos 5.3. Installed using `yum`.

From my `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=company,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=com"
```

From my `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`

```
BASE dc=company,dc=com
```

I have successfully added an entry with `ldapadd` and retrieved it with `ldapsearch` from a local bash shell on the box.

Now I am trying to get a Graphical Editor to connect to this server remotely so I can enter people from my laptop. But I am having no luck. I tried [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/), and it connects with `Anonymous` bind without me having to specify a `BaseDN` but I can't edit anything that way.

If I try and give it a user name and password, using `Manager` and my `rootpw` I have in clear text just for testing, every GUI Client on my remote laptop complains about my `BaseDN` not being the correct format when I enter `dc=company,dc=com` and I tried `cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=com`.

```
Error opening connection:
[LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]
```

I have tried multiple clients and all of them connect as anonymous, none let me connect authenticated where I can actually create or edit anything.

I am using `Manager` as my username and the password from `rootpw`, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to give a fully qualified User DN for the user `cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=com` I was just putting `Manager` in.